# Replacing variable names with variable labels when creating a table in R

Tags: r

I have this data

```
> dat_urg[1:6,1:6]
    FREHT FREMI CFTHR CFAP FARR FANGIO
41    YES   YES    NO   NO   NO    YES
49    YES   YES    NO   NO   NO    YES
94    YES   YES    NO   NO   NO     NO
101   YES   YES    NO   NO   NO     NO
106   YES   YES    NO   NO   NO     NO
138   YES   YES    NO   NO   NO     NO
```

I create Table 1 the following way:

```
library(tableone)
vars_readm <- c("FREHT","FREMI","CFTHR","CFAP","FARR","FANGIO")
> CreateTableOne(vars = vars_readm, data = dat_urg)

               Overall    
  n                556        
  FREHT = YES (%)  494 (88.8) 
  FREMI = YES (%)  435 (78.2) 
  CFTHR = YES (%)   22 ( 4.0) 
  CFAP = YES (%)    39 ( 7.0) 
  FARR = YES (%)    15 ( 2.7) 
  FANGIO = YES (%) 198 (35.6)
```

Now the question is how can I label the variable names so that the output will show the labels instead of the variable names.

For example: instead of existing variables I would like to have the following names:

```
c("Cardiac event driven","RE-MI/UAP","Stent thrombosis","Angina","Arrhythmia","Cor. Angiography")
```

I know there is an option to change the variable names with

```
names(dat_urg) <- c("Cardiac event driven","RE-MI/UAP","Stent thrombosis","Angina","Arrhythmia","Cor. Angiography")
```

but then it is very uncomfortable to continue working with the new names.
Is there any option to define labels and use them only for creating the table I need?

Comment: Couldn't you simply make a temporary copy of `dat_urg` (`dat_urg2 <- dat_urg`), then just rename the columns of that copy (`names(dat_urg2) <- ...`) before calling CreateTableOne and finally remove the copy (`rm(data_urg2)` ) ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep a couple of vectors on hand: `nms <- names(dat_urg); lbl <- c("Cardiac event driven", ...)`.  Then when you need the labels, run `dat_urg <- setNames(dat_urg, lbl)` and toggle back with `dat_urg <- setNames(dat_urg, nms)`

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, wasn't familiar with setNames function.

Comment: I was wondering if there is an option to define once the labels for all variables in the data, and then when I choose a few variables from this data, I would automatically have the label for those variables (like in SAS)